# Wpf grid inside viewbox not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, resize, viewbox

I'm trying to use a viewbox in order to resize the grid within it. The problem is the after I add grid inside the viewbox it distorts all the grid and its childs.
The grid contains a Listview which items have a custom template and style as in the code below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="sectors">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="169*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="287*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Height}" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="Images/drag.png" Width="20" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Cursor="SizeAll" ToolTip="Rivendos" Height="20" Margin="5,40"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{Binding colorO}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0 0 0 8" Cursor="SizeNS"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="mainG">

</Grid>
```

MainWindow class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Viewbox vb = new Viewbox();
            vb.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            Grid shelfGrid = new Grid();
            ListView shelf = new ListView();
            shelf.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            shelf.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["sectors"];
            ObservableCollection<Sector> sectors = new ObservableCollection<Sector>();
            sectors.Add(new Sector() { Id = 1, Width = 100, Height = 100, colorO = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Name = "Sector 1" });
            sectors.Add(new Sector() { Id = 2, Width = 100, Height = 200, colorO = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), Name = "Sector 2" });
            shelf.ItemsSource = sectors;
            shelfGrid.Children.Add(shelf);
            shelfGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            mainG.Children.Add(shelfGrid);
        }

        private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double[] units = calculateUnits(350, 300);
            mainG.Width = units[0];
            mainG.Height = units[1];
        }

        public double[] calculateUnits(double widthR, double heightR)
        {
            double[] units = new double[3];
            double ratio = 0;
            double width = this.ActualWidth;
            double height = this.ActualHeight - 35;
            double maxShelf = Math.Max(widthR, heightR);
            double minPanel = Math.Min(width, height);
            ratio = widthR / heightR;
            if (widthR > heightR)
            {
                units[1] = (width / ratio) - Math.Max(0, (width / ratio) - height);
                units[0] = units[1] * ratio;
            }
            else
            {
                units[0] = (height * ratio) - Math.Max(0, (height * ratio) - width);
                units[1] = units[0] / ratio;
            }
            return units;
        }
    }
}
```

Sector class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    class Sector
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Depth { get; set; }
        public int Color { get; set; }
        public long ShelfId { get; set; }

        public SolidColorBrush colorO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Without viewbox everything seems fine but ListItems doesn't resize
[image: ds]

For example if I resize window as it can be seen below the ListView items height stays the same, instead their height should change and mantain the ratio with its parent:
[image]

With viewbox everything is distorted!!

```
vb.Child = shelfGrid;
mainG.Children.Add(vb);
```

[image]

If I use Stretch.Uniform instead of Stretch.Fill I get this:

[image]

What I'm missing, or I should take another way of achieving that?

Comment: _"I should take another way of achieving that?"_ -- achieving what? You say about your first image that _"ListItems does not scale"_, but you don't explain what "ListItems" is (that name appears nowhere else in your question). What's wrong with the first image? The problem with the second is more clear, but it's a natural consequence of using `Stretch.Fill`. If you use `Stretch.Uniform` or `Stretch.UniformToFill`, your image won't be distorted. But will that result in what you want? We have no idea, because you haven't explained what you _do_ want.

Comment: The problem with the first image is that when I resize the window I want ListView items to be resized (height and button just like zooming) too not just the ListViev - hope I made myself clear.

Comment: I think you are confusing stretching / docking with scaling. The ViewBox will scale children, not necessarily proportionally. Stretching / docking stretches the controls (resizes them) without scaling them, so they are not distorted. Also, coding XAML in C# is a really, really, REALLY bad idea :).

Comment: _"hope I made myself clear"_ -- no, you have not. _"when I resize the window I want ListView items to be resized"_ -- you can accomplish that without distortion if you use `Stretch.Uniform` instead of `Stretch.Fill`. Please explain why you are using what appears to be the wrong `Stretch` value, given your desired result.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I edited the question, maybe now you will be able to understand what I'm trying to achieve. And about why I was using Fill instead of Uniform it's because I was testing. First time that I'm using viewbox!!

Comment: @SledgeHammer I'm having difficulties expressing what Im trying to achieve using words, so Im using more images which can describe better what I want to do (probably). I have used XAML with C# from the beginning, what do you suggest to use instead of C#??

Comment: @ASTeam, you should put it all in the XAML... there is almost never a need to do UI work in the code behind. Even less so when you use MVVM. What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? I get you have a ListView. You want the items to stay the same height, but fill the dialog horizontally as the dialog is resized?

Comment: _"If I use Stretch.Uniform instead of Stretch.Fill I get this"_ -- and what is wrong with that? You continue to state the many different things you _don't_ want. But you have yet to state in any sort of clear way what you _do_ want.